# Parsing specific data from html

Tags: python, html, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

I have extracted the second table alone, and in the 2nd table I need to extract the lines that have a filename in `column[0]`.

```
<TABLE WIDTH="100%" BORDER="1" >
<TR ><TD BGCOLOR="#FFFF99" ROWSPAN="1" COLSPAN="2" WIDTH="70%">Root</TD></TR>
<TR ><TD BGCOLOR="#FFFFCC" ROWSPAN="1" COLSPAN="1" WIDTH="70%">Functions</TD><TD BGCOLOR="#FFFFCC" ROWSPAN="1" COLSPAN="1" WIDTH="30%"> &#160;&#160;&#160;10.1% (1077/10647)</TD></TR>
<TR ><TD BGCOLOR="#FFFFCC" ROWSPAN="1" COLSPAN="1" WIDTH="70%">Functions and exits</TD><TD BGCOLOR="#FFFFCC" ROWSPAN="1" COLSPAN="1" WIDTH="30%"> &#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;9.5% (2142/22473)</TD></TR>
<TR ><TD BGCOLOR="#FFFFCC" ROWSPAN="1" COLSPAN="1" WIDTH="70%">Statement blocks</TD><TD BGCOLOR="#FFFFCC" ROWSPAN="1" COLSPAN="1" WIDTH="30%"> &#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;9.1% (2191/24167)</TD></TR>
<TR ><TD BGCOLOR="#FFFFCC" ROWSPAN="1" COLSPAN="1" WIDTH="70%">Decisions</TD><TD BGCOLOR="#FFFFCC" ROWSPAN="1" COLSPAN="1" WIDTH="30%"> &#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;8.8% (2648/29930)</TD></TR>
<TR ><TD BGCOLOR="#FFFFCC" ROWSPAN="1" COLSPAN="1" WIDTH="70%">Loops</TD><TD BGCOLOR="#FFFFCC" ROWSPAN="1" COLSPAN="1" WIDTH="30%"> &#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;8.4% (305/3628)</TD></TR>
<TR ><TD BGCOLOR="#FFFFCC" ROWSPAN="1" COLSPAN="1" WIDTH="70%">Basic conditions</TD><TD BGCOLOR="#FFFFCC" ROWSPAN="1" COLSPAN="1" WIDTH="30%"> &#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;8.3% (1759/21254)</TD></TR>
<TR ><TD BGCOLOR="#FFFFCC" ROWSPAN="1" COLSPAN="1" WIDTH="70%">Modified conditions</TD><TD BGCOLOR="#FFFFCC" ROWSPAN="1" COLSPAN="1" WIDTH="30%"> &#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;1.8% (35/1997)</TD></TR>
<TR ><TD BGCOLOR="#FFFFCC" ROWSPAN="1" COLSPAN="1" WIDTH="70%">Multiple conditions</TD><TD BGCOLOR="#FFFFCC" ROWSPAN="1" COLSPAN="1" WIDTH="30%"> &#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;4.4% (137/3082)</TD></TR>

</TABLE>
</P>
<P ALIGN="LEFT"><BR>
2 - Files list</P>
<BR>
Display absolute values only.<BR>

<TABLE WIDTH="100%" BORDER="1" >
<TR BGCOLOR="#FFFF99"><TD BGCOLOR="#FFFF99" ROWSPAN="1" COLSPAN="1" WIDTH="27%"><b>Item<IMG SRC="cvi_sort_d.png" ALT="cvi_sort_d.xpm"></b></TD><TD BGCOLOR="#FFFF99" ROWSPAN="1" COLSPAN="1" WIDTH="9%"><b>Functions</b></TD><TD BGCOLOR="#FFFF99" ROWSPAN="1" COLSPAN="1" WIDTH="9%"><b>Functions and exits</b></TD><TD BGCOLOR="#FFFF99" ROWSPAN="1" COLSPAN="1" WIDTH="9%"><b>Statement blocks</b></TD><TD BGCOLOR="#FFFF99" ROWSPAN="1" COLSPAN="1" WIDTH="9%"><b>Decisions</b></TD><TD BGCOLOR="#FFFF99" ROWSPAN="1" COLSPAN="1" WIDTH="9%"><b>Loops</b></TD><TD BGCOLOR="#FFFF99" ROWSPAN="1" COLSPAN="1" WIDTH="9%"><b>Basic conditions</b></TD><TD BGCOLOR="#FFFF99" ROWSPAN="1" COLSPAN="1" WIDTH="9%"><b>Modified conditions</b></TD><TD BGCOLOR="#FFFF99" ROWSPAN="1" COLSPAN="1" WIDTH="9%"><b>Multiple conditions</b></TD></TR>
<TR ><TD BGCOLOR="#FF9999" ROWSPAN="1" COLSPAN="1" WIDTH="27%"><B><A NAME="175746848"></A><a href="LOADER.H.html">LOADER.H</a></B></TD><TD BGCOLOR="#FFDFDD" ROWSPAN="1" COLSPAN="1" WIDTH="9%"><P ALIGN="RIGHT">0/1</P>
</TD><TD BGCOLOR="#FFDFDD" ROWSPAN="1" COLSPAN="1" WIDTH="9%"><P ALIGN="RIGHT">0/2</P>
</TD><TD BGCOLOR="#FFDFDD" ROWSPAN="1" COLSPAN="1" WIDTH="9%"><P ALIGN="RIGHT">0/1</P>
</TD><TD BGCOLOR="#FFDFDD" ROWSPAN="1" COLSPAN="1" WIDTH="9%"><P ALIGN="RIGHT">0/1</P>
</TD><TD BGCOLOR="#CCCCFF" ROWSPAN="1" COLSPAN="1" WIDTH="9%"><P ALIGN="RIGHT">none </P>
</TD><TD BGCOLOR="#CCCCFF" ROWSPAN="1" COLSPAN="1" WIDTH="9%"><P ALIGN="RIGHT">none </P>
</TD><TD BGCOLOR="#CCCCFF" ROWSPAN="1" COLSPAN="1" WIDTH="9%"><P ALIGN="RIGHT">none </P>
</TD><TD BGCOLOR="#CCCCFF" ROWSPAN="1" COLSPAN="1" WIDTH="9%"><P ALIGN="RIGHT">none </P>
</TD></TR>
<TR ><TD BGCOLOR="#9999FF" ROWSPAN="1" COLSPAN="1" WIDTH="27%"><A NAME="175746912"></A> &#160;&#160;&#160;<a href="LOADER.H.html">LoaderState_struct</a></TD><TD BGCOLOR="#CCCCFF" ROWSPAN="1" COLSPAN="1" WIDTH="9%"><P ALIGN="RIGHT">none </P>
</TD><TD BGCOLOR="#CCCCFF" ROWSPAN="1" COLSPAN="1" WIDTH="9%"><P ALIGN="RIGHT">none </P>
</TD><TD BGCOLOR="#CCCCFF" ROWSPAN="1" COLSPAN="1" WIDTH="9%"><P ALIGN="RIGHT">none </P>
</TD><TD BGCOLOR="#CCCCFF" ROWSPAN="1" COLSPAN="1" WIDTH="9%"><P ALIGN="RIGHT">none </P>
</TD><TD BGCOLOR="#CCCCFF" ROWSPAN="1" COLSPAN="1" WIDTH="9%"><P ALIGN="RIGHT">none </P>
</TD><TD BGCOLOR="#CCCCFF" ROWSPAN="1" COLSPAN="1" WIDTH="9%"><P ALIGN="RIGHT">none </P>
</TD><TD BGCOLOR="#CCCCFF" ROWSPAN="1" COLSPAN="1" WIDTH="9%"><P ALIGN="RIGHT">none </P>
</TD><TD BGCOLOR="#CCCCFF" ROWSPAN="1" COLSPAN="1" WIDTH="9%"><P ALIGN="RIGHT">none </P>
</TD></TR>
<TR ><TD BGCOLOR="#9999FF" ROWSPAN="1" COLSPAN="1" WIDTH="27%"><A NAME="175746976"></A> &#160;&#160;&#160;<a href="LOADER.H.html">LoadParameters_struct</a></TD><TD BGCOLOR="#CCCCFF" ROWSPAN="1" COLSPAN="1" WIDTH="9%"><P ALIGN="RIGHT">none </P>
</TD><TD BGCOLOR="#CCCCFF" ROWSPAN="1" COLSPAN="1" WIDTH="9%"><P ALIGN="RIGHT">none </P>
</TD><TD BGCOLOR="#CCCCFF" ROWSPAN="1" COLSPAN="1" WIDTH="9%"><P ALIGN="RIGHT">none </P>
</TD><TD BGCOLOR="#CCCCFF" ROWSPAN="1" COLSPAN="1" WIDTH="9%"><P ALIGN="RIGHT">none </P>
</TD><TD BGCOLOR="#CCCCFF" ROWSPAN="1" COLSPAN="1" WIDTH="9%"><P ALIGN="RIGHT">none </P>
</TD><TD BGCOLOR="#CCCCFF" ROWSPAN="1" COLSPAN="1" WIDTH="9%"><P ALIGN="RIGHT">none </P>
</TD><TD BGCOLOR="#CCCCFF" ROWSPAN="1" COLSPAN="1" WIDTH="9%"><P ALIGN="RIGHT">none </P>
</TD><TD BGCOLOR="#CCCCFF" ROWSPAN="1" COLSPAN="1" WIDTH="9%"><P ALIGN="RIGHT">none </P>
</TD></TR>
<TR ><TD BGCOLOR="#9999FF" ROWSPAN="1" COLSPAN="1" WIDTH="27%"><A NAME="175747104"></A> &#160;&#160;&#160;<a href="LOADER.H.html">LoadOffsets_struct</a></TD><TD BGCOLOR="#CCCCFF" ROWSPAN="1" COLSPAN="1" WIDTH="9%"><P ALIGN="RIGHT">none </P>
</TD><TD BGCOLOR="#CCCCFF" ROWSPAN="1" COLSPAN="1" WIDTH="9%"><P ALIGN="RIGHT">none </P>
</TD><TD BGCOLOR="#CCCCFF" ROWSPAN="1" COLSPAN="1" WIDTH="9%"><P ALIGN="RIGHT">none </P>
</TD><TD BGCOLOR="#CCCCFF" ROWSPAN="1" COLSPAN="1" WIDTH="9%"><P ALIGN="RIGHT">none </P>
</TD><TD BGCOLOR="#CCCCFF" ROWSPAN="1" COLSPAN="1" WIDTH="9%"><P ALIGN="RIGHT">none </P>
</TD><TD BGCOLOR="#CCCCFF" ROWSPAN="1" COLSPAN="1" WIDTH="9%"><P ALIGN="RIGHT">none </P>
</TD><TD BGCOLOR="#CCCCFF" ROWSPAN="1" COLSPAN="1" WIDTH="9%"><P ALIGN="RIGHT">none </P>
</TD><TD BGCOLOR="#CCCCFF" ROWSPAN="1" COLSPAN="1" WIDTH="9%"><P ALIGN="RIGHT">none </P>
</TD></TR>
<TR ><TD BGCOLOR="#9999FF" ROWSPAN="1" COLSPAN="1" WIDTH="27%"><A NAME="175747168"></A> &#160;&#160;&#160;<a href="LOADER.H.html">LoadAppComponent_struct</a></TD><TD BGCOLOR="#CCCCFF" ROWSPAN="1" COLSPAN="1" WIDTH="9%"><P ALIGN="RIGHT">none </P>
</TD><TD BGCOLOR="#CCCCFF" ROWSPAN="1" COLSPAN="1" WIDTH="9%"><P ALIGN="RIGHT">none </P>
</TD><TD BGCOLOR="#CCCCFF" ROWSPAN="1" COLSPAN="1" WIDTH="9%"><P ALIGN="RIGHT">none </P>
</TD><TD BGCOLOR="#CCCCFF" ROWSPAN="1" COLSPAN="1" WIDTH="9%"><P ALIGN="RIGHT">none </P>
</TD><TD BGCOLOR="#CCCCFF" ROWSPAN="1" COLSPAN="1" WIDTH="9%"><P ALIGN="RIGHT">none </P>
</TD><TD BGCOLOR="#CCCCFF" ROWSPAN="1" COLSPAN="1" WIDTH="9%"><P ALIGN="RIGHT">none </P>
</TD><TD BGCOLOR="#CCCCFF" ROWSPAN="1" COLSPAN="1" WIDTH="9%"><P ALIGN="RIGHT">none </P>
</TD><TD BGCOLOR="#CCCCFF" ROWSPAN="1" COLSPAN="1" WIDTH="9%"><P ALIGN="RIGHT">none </P>
</TD></TR>
<TR ><TD BGCOLOR="#FF9999" ROWSPAN="1" COLSPAN="1" WIDTH="27%"><B><A NAME="175746848"></A><a href="CORBA_FIXED.CC.html">CORBA_FIXED.CC</a></B></TD><TD BGCOLOR="#FFDFDD" ROWSPAN="1" COLSPAN="1" WIDTH="9%"><P ALIGN="RIGHT">0/1</P>
</TD><TD BGCOLOR="#FFDFDD" ROWSPAN="1" COLSPAN="1" WIDTH="9%"><P ALIGN="RIGHT">0/2</P>
</TD><TD BGCOLOR="#FFDFDD" ROWSPAN="1" COLSPAN="1" WIDTH="9%"><P ALIGN="RIGHT">0/1</P>
</TD><TD BGCOLOR="#FFDFDD" ROWSPAN="1" COLSPAN="1" WIDTH="9%"><P ALIGN="RIGHT">0/1</P>
</TD><TD BGCOLOR="#CCCCFF" ROWSPAN="1" COLSPAN="1" WIDTH="9%"><P ALIGN="RIGHT">none </P>
</TD><TD BGCOLOR="#CCCCFF" ROWSPAN="1" COLSPAN="1" WIDTH="9%"><P ALIGN="RIGHT">none </P>
</TD><TD BGCOLOR="#CCCCFF" ROWSPAN="1" COLSPAN="1" WIDTH="9%"><P ALIGN="RIGHT">none </P>
</TD><TD BGCOLOR="#CCCCFF" ROWSPAN="1" COLSPAN="1" WIDTH="9%"><P ALIGN="RIGHT">none </P>
</TD></TR>
<TR ><TD BGCOLOR="#9999FF" ROWSPAN="1" COLSPAN="1" WIDTH="27%"><A NAME="175746912"></A> &#160;&#160;&#160;<a href="LOADER.H.html">LoaderState_struct</a></TD><TD BGCOLOR="#CCCCFF" ROWSPAN="1" COLSPAN="1" WIDTH="9%"><P ALIGN="RIGHT">none </P>
</TD><TD BGCOLOR="#CCCCFF" ROWSPAN="1" COLSPAN="1" WIDTH="9%"><P ALIGN="RIGHT">none </P>
</TD><TD BGCOLOR="#CCCCFF" ROWSPAN="1" COLSPAN="1" WIDTH="9%"><P ALIGN="RIGHT">none </P>
</TD><TD BGCOLOR="#CCCCFF" ROWSPAN="1" COLSPAN="1" WIDTH="9%"><P ALIGN="RIGHT">none </P>
</TD><TD BGCOLOR="#CCCCFF" ROWSPAN="1" COLSPAN="1" WIDTH="9%"><P ALIGN="RIGHT">none </P>
</TD><TD BGCOLOR="#CCCCFF" ROWSPAN="1" COLSPAN="1" WIDTH="9%"><P ALIGN="RIGHT">none </P>
</TD><TD BGCOLOR="#CCCCFF" ROWSPAN="1" COLSPAN="1" WIDTH="9%"><P ALIGN="RIGHT">none </P>
</TD><TD BGCOLOR="#CCCCFF" ROWSPAN="1" COLSPAN="1" WIDTH="9%"><P ALIGN="RIGHT">none </P>
</TD></TR>
<TR ><TD BGCOLOR="#9999FF" ROWSPAN="1" COLSPAN="1" WIDTH="27%"><A NAME="175746976"></A> &#160;&#160;&#160;<a href="LOADER.H.html">LoadParameters_struct</a></TD><TD BGCOLOR="#CCCCFF" ROWSPAN="1" COLSPAN="1" WIDTH="9%"><P ALIGN="RIGHT">none </P>
</TD><TD BGCOLOR="#CCCCFF" ROWSPAN="1" COLSPAN="1" WIDTH="9%"><P ALIGN="RIGHT">none </P>
</TD><TD BGCOLOR="#CCCCFF" ROWSPAN="1" COLSPAN="1" WIDTH="9%"><P ALIGN="RIGHT">none </P>
</TD><TD BGCOLOR="#CCCCFF" ROWSPAN="1" COLSPAN="1" WIDTH="9%"><P ALIGN="RIGHT">none </P>
</TD><TD BGCOLOR="#CCCCFF" ROWSPAN="1" COLSPAN="1" WIDTH="9%"><P ALIGN="RIGHT">none </P>
</TD><TD BGCOLOR="#CCCCFF" ROWSPAN="1" COLSPAN="1" WIDTH="9%"><P ALIGN="RIGHT">none </P>
</TD><TD BGCOLOR="#CCCCFF" ROWSPAN="1" COLSPAN="1" WIDTH="9%"><P ALIGN="RIGHT">none </P>
</TD><TD BGCOLOR="#CCCCFF" ROWSPAN="1" COLSPAN="1" WIDTH="9%"><P ALIGN="RIGHT">none </P>
</TD></TR>
<TR ><TD BGCOLOR="#9999FF" ROWSPAN="1" COLSPAN="1" WIDTH="27%"><A NAME="175747104"></A> &#160;&#160;&#160;<a href="LOADER.H.html">LoadOffsets_struct</a></TD><TD BGCOLOR="#CCCCFF" ROWSPAN="1" COLSPAN="1" WIDTH="9%"><P ALIGN="RIGHT">none </P>
</TD><TD BGCOLOR="#CCCCFF" ROWSPAN="1" COLSPAN="1" WIDTH="9%"><P ALIGN="RIGHT">none </P>
</TD><TD BGCOLOR="#CCCCFF" ROWSPAN="1" COLSPAN="1" WIDTH="9%"><P ALIGN="RIGHT">none </P>
</TD><TD BGCOLOR="#CCCCFF" ROWSPAN="1" COLSPAN="1" WIDTH="9%"><P ALIGN="RIGHT">none </P>
</TD><TD BGCOLOR="#CCCCFF" ROWSPAN="1" COLSPAN="1" WIDTH="9%"><P ALIGN="RIGHT">none </P>
</TD><TD BGCOLOR="#CCCCFF" ROWSPAN="1" COLSPAN="1" WIDTH="9%"><P ALIGN="RIGHT">none </P>
</TD><TD BGCOLOR="#CCCCFF" ROWSPAN="1" COLSPAN="1" WIDTH="9%"><P ALIGN="RIGHT">none </P>
</TD><TD BGCOLOR="#CCCCFF" ROWSPAN="1" COLSPAN="1" WIDTH="9%"><P ALIGN="RIGHT">none </P>
</TD></TR>
<TR ><TD BGCOLOR="#9999FF" ROWSPAN="1" COLSPAN="1" WIDTH="27%"><A NAME="175747168"></A> &#160;&#160;&#160;<a href="LOADER.H.html">LoadAppComponent_struct</a></TD><TD BGCOLOR="#CCCCFF" ROWSPAN="1" COLSPAN="1" WIDTH="9%"><P ALIGN="RIGHT">none </P>
</TD><TD BGCOLOR="#CCCCFF" ROWSPAN="1" COLSPAN="1" WIDTH="9%"><P ALIGN="RIGHT">none </P>
</TD><TD BGCOLOR="#CCCCFF" ROWSPAN="1" COLSPAN="1" WIDTH="9%"><P ALIGN="RIGHT">none </P>
</TD><TD BGCOLOR="#CCCCFF" ROWSPAN="1" COLSPAN="1" WIDTH="9%"><P ALIGN="RIGHT">none </P>
</TD><TD BGCOLOR="#CCCCFF" ROWSPAN="1" COLSPAN="1" WIDTH="9%"><P ALIGN="RIGHT">none </P>
</TD><TD BGCOLOR="#CCCCFF" ROWSPAN="1" COLSPAN="1" WIDTH="9%"><P ALIGN="RIGHT">none </P>
</TD><TD BGCOLOR="#CCCCFF" ROWSPAN="1" COLSPAN="1" WIDTH="9%"><P ALIGN="RIGHT">none </P>
</TD><TD BGCOLOR="#CCCCFF" ROWSPAN="1" COLSPAN="1" WIDTH="9%"><P ALIGN="RIGHT">none </P>
</TD></TR>
</TABLE>
```

For this parsing I had written a python script as follows:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
f = open("/home/vignesh/Downloads/html/RateDoc.html","r")
fl = {'LOADER.H','CORBA_FIXED.H'}
soup = BeautifulSoup(f)
t = soup.findAll('table')
for table in t[1:]:
    rows = table.findAll('tr')
    for tr in rows[1:]:
        cols = tr.findAll('td')
        for td in cols:
            text = ''.join((td.find(text=True)).encode('utf-8'))
            print text+"\t",
        print
    print


the above script extracts the data as follows:


LOADER.H    0/1 0/2 0/1 0/1 none    none    none    none    
        none    none    none    none    none    none    none    none    
        none    none    none    none    none    none    none    none    
        none    none    none    none    none    none    none    none    
        none    none    none    none    none    none    none    none    
CORBA_FIXED.CC  0/1 0/2 0/1 0/1 none    none    none    none    
        none    none    none    none    none    none    none    none    
        none    none    none    none    none    none    none    none    
        none    none    none    none    none    none    none    none    
        none    none    none    none    none    none    none    none
```

But the expected result is as follows, I want to extract all files with extension `*.cc` or `*.h`

Output Required:

```
LOADER.H    0/1 0/2 0/1 0/1 none    none    none    none    
CORBA_FIXED.CC  0/1 0/2 0/1 0/1 none    none    none    none
```

Can someone help me modifying the above script so that it extracts the specific extensions `*.cc` and `*.h`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

INPUT = "/home/vignesh/Downloads/html/RateDoc.html"

def main():
    with open(INPUT, "rb") as inf:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(inf)

    for row in soup.findAll("tr"):
        first_col = row.find("td")
        links = first_col.findAll("a")
        if len(links) == 2:
            link_text = links[1].text
            parts = link_text.rsplit(".", 1)
            if len(parts) > 1 and parts[-1].lower() in {"h", "cc"}:
                # print row
                print("\t".join(cell.text.strip().encode("utf-8") for cell in row.findAll("td")))
```

produces

```
LOADER.H    0/1 0/2 0/1 0/1 none    none    none    none
CORBA_FIXED.CC  0/1 0/2 0/1 0/1 none    none    none    none
```

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that if you encapsulate your data in an if, that it should work.  Based on the fact that the initial print of the lines that you want to skip seem to show a blank entry
followed by the eight values of 'none'

```
if text is '':
  break
else:
  print text + '\t',
```

This is from inspection of your code only as I am not currently in a position to test it.